# OpenCv BruterForceMatcher Failed while drawMatches

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

With following OpenCV code I try to test the BruteForceMatcher and get error message:
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in cv::drawKeypoints, file C:
\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\featur
es2d\src\draw.cpp, line 115

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp"
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
#define MAX_PICNUM 18
bool try_use_gpu = false;
vector<Mat> imgs;
string result_name = "result.jpg";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    initModule_nonfree();
    int picNum = 2;
    Mat imgs[MAX_PICNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < picNum; ++i) {
        stringstream ss;
        string iStr;
        ss << i;
        ss >> iStr;
        imgs[i] = imread("../" + iStr + ".jpg");
    }
    SiftFeatureDetector siftdtc;
    vector<KeyPoint> keyPointVec[MAX_PICNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < picNum; ++i) {
        siftdtc.detect(imgs[i], keyPointVec[i]);
    }
    SiftDescriptorExtractor siftDesc;
    Mat descriptextractors[MAX_PICNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < picNum; ++i) {
        siftDesc.compute(imgs[i], keyPointVec[i], descriptextractors[i]);
    }
    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptor1,descriptor2;
    BruteForceMatcher<L2<float>> matcher;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    Mat img_matches;
    extractor.compute(imgs[0], keyPointVec[0], descriptor1);
    extractor.compute(imgs[1], keyPointVec[1], descriptor2);
    matcher.match(descriptor1,descriptor2,matches);
    drawMatches(imgs[0], keyPointVec[0], imgs[1], keyPointVec[1], matches, img_matches);

    cvSaveImage("matchs.jpg", &(IplImage)(img_matches));
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like it is the error in drawMatches?

Comment: better check whether keyPointVec[0] or keyPointVec[1] or matches is empty. but it looks like your output image may not be empty

Comment: not the error but please change      cvSaveImage("matchs.jpg", &(IplImage)(img_matches)); to cv::imwrite("matchs.jpg", (img_matches));

Comment: give this a try: drawMatches(imgs[0], keyPointVec[0], imgs[1], keyPointVec[1], matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1),Scalar::all(-1),vector<vector<char> >(),DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

Comment: Looks like the keyPoints should not be stored in an array, I use variable name like keyPoints1,keyPoints2 instead and the problem is solved. Thanks